# php app / console stops working

Tags: php, symfony, web, terminal, mamp

After a slight modification of my units, I wanted the update with a simple `php app/console doctrine: update --force`. But no action executed and in addition no response. I then did a `php app/check.php` meaning me no problems (`Your system is ready to run Symfony2 projects`). I do not understand and it doesn't provide an error. Here's what I've done:

```
Command: ********: ***** ProjetSymphony $ php app / console***
Answer (none): ******* **** $ ProjetSymphony***
```

If someone has an idea.

Screen :

[image]

Comment: please post screenshot of your terminal when you running that command

Comment: She referred me anything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, if anyone tries to run `php app/console` in a newer symfony version (for example symfony 3.0), you will get an error: no file found because the file was moved to 'bin' folder. Now to run from the console, you have to use `php bin/console` instead. Just in case this change confused anyone who started to learn symfony and updated to 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Maybe it's only a syntaxis error.

Comment: your console is running into your symfony application path?

Comment: supose that your symfony projects is in: "C:\user\user1\symofony\project" you need to start your console in the same path.

Comment: I use my my mac Terminal application made for my order. But the mistake of not from the Terminal pyisque command always works on other projects ...

Comment: do you have `new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),` into your AppKernel.php?

Comment: Yes, i have a doctrine bundle in my AppKernel.php

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my mistake. I had a command file that prevented the execution of my order (***CreateUserCommand.php***)
If someone wants to explain to me why this cosait file an error during the execution of my order ... 
Here is the file :

```
<?php

namespace FP\UserBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand as BaseCommand;

class CreateUserCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        exit;
        echo "tes";
        parent::configure();
        $this
            ->setName('fp:user:create')
            ->getDefinition()->addArguments(array(
                new InputArgument('age', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The age')
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exit;
        echo "tes";
        $username   = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email      = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password   = $input->getArgument('password');
        $age        = $input->getArgument('age');
        $inactive   = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');

        $manipulator = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.util.user_manipulator');
        $manipulator->setAge($age);
        $manipulator->create($username, $password, $email, !$inactive, $superadmin);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        exit;
        echo "tes";
        parent::interact($input, $output);
        if (!$input->getArgument('age')) {
            $age = $this->getHelper('dialog')->askAndValidate(
                $output,
                'Please choose a age:',
                function($age) {
                    if (empty($age)) {
                        throw new \Exception('Lastname can not be empty');
                    }

                    return $age;
                }
            );
            $input->setArgument('age', $age);
        }
    }
}
```